# Thymeleaf with nested (recursive) evaluation and th:replace

Tags: replace, include, nested, fragment, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a Template that allows me to pass an attribute to the model specifying the name of the fragment that will be used to replace a div-tag in my template.

The template code is:

```
    <div th:replace="${__${T(mypackage.WebUtils).INCLUDE_FRAGMENT_NAME}__}"/>
```

(the value of INCLUDE_FRAGMENT_NAME is "fragment".
In my controller I have:

```
model.addAttribute(WebUtils.INCLUDE_FRAGMENT_NAME, WebUtils.MAIN_OVERVIEW_DIV_INCLUDE);
```

with MAIN_OVERVIEW_DIV_INCLUDE being "main/main :: fragment".

The error I get is this one:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates/main/main :: fragment.html]" - line 43, col 14)

I understand that the URL is wrong but I have no idea on how to fix that. Any help?

Also, it would be nice if I could set the fragment name in main/main dynamically but I guess that's out of the question as the fragment isn't evaluated before being included, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/77 - changing the code to

`<div th:replace="${__${T(mypackage.WebUtils).INCLUDE_FILE_VAR_NAME}__} :: ${__${T(mypackage.WebUtils).INCLUDE_FRAGMENT_VAR_NAME}__}"/>`

fixed the problem for me. For the dynamic fragment name, see http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Thymeleaf-3-with-nested-recursive-evaluation-and-th-replace-td4029392.html#a4029395